# Allow non-administrators to use diskpart to mount VHDs?

Tags: windows, vhd

What permissions does one need specifically to allow non-administrative users to use the diskpart utility, in this case, to mount and dismount VHDs in Windows 7?  This is more complex than granting Disk Volume Management. There appears to be additional DCOM privs needed for various objects (Virtual Drive Service, for one), and I am having trouble tracking them down.

Comment: I expect that the only solution is to install a service to perform these tasks on the user's behalf.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, I'm not sure this is possible.  The official word from Microsoft (I don't have a reference to provide, but I used to work there and this was the message I got) is that mounting and unmounting VHDs can only be performed by administrators.  ISOs, on the other hand, can be mounted and unmounted by regular users.

If you do manage to figure out a way to do it by granting specific privs to non-admin users, I suspect that it would be "unsupported".

Answer (score 3):

I found a tool VHDAttach:
http://www.jmedved.com/vhdattach/
Which adds a Windows Service that runs as a privileged account, that recieves messages from a little exe, and add shell extensions so that non-priv users can attach/detach VHDs.

Comment: If you're installing this as part of your own software package (under the terms of the MIT license, I'm sure!) make sure you customize it specific to your needs.  Otherwise it could have an adverse impact on your customer's security.

Comment: This is gold!!!